# New desktop,server not found,how to connect with wire?

Tags: networking, internet

I have bought new desktop(with Ubuntu 16.04 on it).Now when I try to connect it to modem, it shows connection in upper right corner.But there is no connection.

From terminal

```
ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

With `ifconfig`

```
enp3s0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 70:......

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
```

In terminal

```
lspci | grep Network
```

gives nothing.This point to drivers not installed,yes or no?

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolve.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by reolveconf(8)
```

Terminal route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.129.32.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
10.129.32.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp3s0
```

I have googled a lot,so I gave a try like this

and

```
    cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
    address 10.129.45.123
    netmask 255.255.224.0
    gateway 10.129.32.1
    up ethtool -s enp3s0 wol g
```

But I have the same problem ,no connection.

What should I try now?

Comment: Have you shorten the enp3s0 output since it seems a little short, you shouldn't be afraid of telling what HWaddr you have or which private address range you use. Of course you can censor any web servers public IP address if you so desire.

Comment: If you have an ip address you can provide us with your "route" output and your "/etc/resolv.conf". Because right now it seems to me that you are just missing a DNS.

Comment: @Ziazis Yes,I have shorten it because I am coping to my laptop.How should I edit /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: You can try adding a DNS manually by adding "nameserver 8.8.8.8" that is the google DNS. If you can ping after that it means you have to adjust your dhcp server to also tell the clients what dns they should use. Usually it's the dhcp-server(router) itself that just forwards the queries to another one.

Comment: Can you add the output of the command "route -n" aswell.

Comment: So did adding a nameserver fix your problem?

Comment: @Ziazis No,I have tried everything but still the same.